# how to shifted phases in PWM with PIC18F4431

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, phase-shift, xc8

I am trying to design a driver for a BLDC motor.

I have managed to generate 6 PWM signals with the PIC18F4431.

But I don't know how I can shifted the phases.

I attach my code and the image of the PWM signals.

```
void pwm_inicialitze(void)
{
  PORTB=0x00;
  TRISBbits.TRISB0=0; 
  TRISBbits.TRISB1=0;
  TRISBbits.TRISB2=0;
  TRISBbits.TRISB3=0;
  TRISBbits.TRISB5=0; 
  TRISBbits.TRISB4=0; 

  INTCON=0XC0;  
  IPR3bits.PTIP=1;
  PIE3bits.PTIE=1;
  PIR3bits.PTIF=0;

  SEVTCMPL=0X00;
  SEVTCMPH=0X00;
  DTCON=8;
  FLTCONFIG=0X00;
  OVDCOND=0XFF;
  OVDCONS=0X00;

  PTMRL=0X00;
  PTMRH=0X00;
  PTCON0=0X00;
  PTCON1=0X80;
  PWMCON0=0X50;
  PWMCON1=0X01;
  PTPERL=124;           
  PTPERH=0;     

  PDC0L=60;         
  PDC0H=0;  
  PDC1L=60;         
  PDC1H=0;  
  PDC2L=60;         
  PDC2H=0;      
  PDC3L=60;         
  PDC3H=0;          

  ADCON0=0x00;
}

void main(void)
{
   ANSEL0=0X00;
   ANSEL1=0X00; 
   pwm_inicialitze();
   while(1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe have a look at the dead time generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller has an enhanced PWM with dead band control. Have a look [here](https://microchipdeveloper.com/8bit:epwmdead).
You should be able to program a delay with the `DTCON`register between your PWMs.